# How to resize product images in recently viewed widget

Tags: magento2, product-images, phtml, widgets, widget

How can I resize the images rendered via the recently viewed product widget?

I have tried editing multiple values inside

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/etc/view.xml

but none updated the recently viewed image sizes.

They are currently rendering at **135px** in **height** and **width**, the only values set at 135 is `shared_wishlist_email` and `product_small_image`. Neither of those changed the image size.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similarly but for the img on the product page. What I did:
 I changed the block that load my img.

In my di.xml:

```
 <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
        <plugin name="plugin_block_catalog_product_view_gallery"
                type="Namespace\Vendor\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Gallery"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
 </type>
```

and i rewrite this block by changing the path of the img like this :

```
public function getGalleryImagesJson()
    {   
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $imagesItems = [];
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {

            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product/'.$image['file'],
                'img' => $this->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product/'.$image['file'],
                'full' => $this->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product/'.$image['file'],
                'caption' => $image->getLabel(),
                'position' => $image->getPosition(),
                'isMain' => $this->isMainImage($image),
            ];
        }
        if (empty($imagesItems)) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('thumbnail'),
                'img' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'full' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'caption' => '',
                'position' => '0',
                'isMain' => true,
            ];
        }
        return json_encode($imagesItems);
    }
```

I know is not what you need, but this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your view.xml:

```
<image id="recently_compared_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
   <width>110</width>
   <height>110</height>
</image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sajid Iqbal Answer - In Magento 2.4.3 / 2.4.4 you can use this.

/design/YourTheme/Name/etc/view.xml

```
<image id="recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget" type="thumbnail">
    <width>196</width>
    <height>196</height>
</image>
```

Reference:
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/viewed/sidebar.phtml

```
'image' => [
        'imageCode' => 'recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget'
    ]
```

After your modification you must run: `bin/magento s:upgrade`